# More than one migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'ForApi'. Specify the name of the one to use

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I did a migration first time and it works but when I open my project after sometime it shows something like this. I did the same migrations for days.

**System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException: 'Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration.
Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.'**

when I trying to update database again show something like this in the package manager console

**Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled.
Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration.
Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
You can use the Add-Migration command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.**
[Package Manager console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ36V.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have created configurations thus you have to specify the configuration name .

```
add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName BaseConfiguration(this is your config name)
```

Also consider using CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli